# How to check if current user belongs to a company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nomethoderror

I want to check if current user belongs to a company and if it does redirect to `root_path` or redirect to `new_company_path`.

I get

```
"NoMethodError in ExpensesController#new undefined method `company_user' 
for #<ExpensesController:0x57ba1c8>"
```

But I tried different way but still not working, if you can tell me where the issue is, that would be very kind of you. Thanks.

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_filter *(I also tried before_action)* :company_user

  private
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
                               u.permit(:username,
                                        :country,
                                        :email,
                                        :password)
                                             }
  end

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "login"
    else
      "application"
      en
    end
```

end < moved from company_user

```
    def company_user
      if current_user.companies.nil?
        redirect_to new_companies_path
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end <the issue was there, I moved it to layout_by_resource.

end
```

edit
** User.rb**

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base**
  #default_value_for :role, "1"
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :timesheets
 has_many :expenses
  has_many :jobdescriptions
  belongs_to :companies
end
```

Expenses controller

```html
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
 layout 'application'

def new
    @expense = Expense.new
end

def create
    @expense = current_user.expenses.create(expense_params)
redirect_to new_expense_path

      
end

#  def serve
#    @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
#    send_data(@expense.data, :type => @expense.mime_type, :filename => "#{@expense.name}.jpg", :disposition => "inline")
#  end

private

def expense_params
  params.require(:expense).permit(:amount, :user_id, :weeknum, :data, :date,)
end

end
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the `app/models/user.rb` source code?

Comment: Your error references `ExpensesController`, but you posted the `ApplicationController`. Please also post `ExpensesController`.

Comment: @wintermeyer, I added my user model.thanks.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, Expenses controller added.

Comment: I fixed the issue, the problem was the last "end" from company_user, sorry for wasting your time.